# Pandas Dataframe removes to much rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, twitter

I have a dataframe with a lot of tweets and i want to remove the duplicates. The tweets are stored in fh1.df['Tweets']. i counts the amount of non-duplicates. j the amount of duplicates. In the else statement I remove the lines of the duplicates. And in the if I make a new list "tweetChecklist" where I put all the good tweets in.

Ok, if I do i + j , i become the amount of original tweets. So that's good. But in the else, I don't know why, he removes to much rows because the shape of my dataframe is much smaller after the for loop (1/10).

How does the   "        fh1.df = fh1.df[fh1.df.Tweets != current_tweet]
" line remove to much rows??

```
tweetChecklist = []
for current_tweet in fh1.df['Tweets']:
    if current_tweet not in tweetChecklist:
        i = i + 1
        tweetChecklist.append(current_tweet)
    else:
        j = j + 1
        fh1.df = fh1.df[fh1.df.Tweets != current_tweet]

fh1.df['Tweets'] = pd.Series(tweetChecklist)
```

Comment: Just use `fh1.df = fh1.df.groupby("Tweets", as_index=False).first()`?

Comment: @Graipher what does that statement do? thanks for answering :)

Comment: It takes for every unique tweet just the one that occurred first. So exactl what you wanted to achieve with this code?

Comment: Yes, it works! Thank you!!

Comment: I'll write it up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### NOTE

Graipher's solution tells you how to generate a unique dataframe.  My answer tells you why your current operation removes too many rows (per your question).

#### END NOTE

When you enter the "else" statement to remove the duplicated tweet you are removing ALL of the rows that have the specified tweet.  Let's demonstrate:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.randint(0, 10, (10, 5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
```

What does this make:

```
Out[118]: 
   A  B  C  D  E
0  2  7  0  5  4
1  2  8  8  3  7
2  9  7  4  6  2
3  9  7  7  9  2
4  6  5  7  6  8
5  8  8  7  6  7
6  6  1  4  5  3
7  1  4  7  8  7
8  3  2  5  8  5
9  5  8  9  2  4
```

In your method (assume you want to remove duplicates from "A" instead of "Tweets") you would end up with (i.e. only have rows that were not unique).

```
Out[118]: 
   A  B  C  D  E
5  8  8  7  6  7
7  1  4  7  8  7
8  3  2  5  8  5
9  5  8  9  2  4
```

If you just want to make this unique, implement Graipher's suggestion.  If you want to count how many duplicates you have you can do this:

```
total = df.shape[0]
duplicates = total - df.A.unique().size
```

Comment: So when there is a duplicate, it removes both the rows. How can i keep one?

Comment: Graipher's solution will keep one of the rows.  In your original code you were removing both rows.  Not only does Graipher's solution do what you want, it will be orders of magnitude faster than your original code.

Answer (score 1):

In `pandas` there is usually always a better way than iterating over the dataframe with a `for` loop.

In this case, what you really want is to group equal tweets together and just retain the first one. This can be achieved with [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
import random
import string
import pandas as pd

# some random one character tweets, so there are many duplicates
df = pd.DataFrame({"Tweets": random.choices(string.ascii_lowercase, k=100),
                   "Data": [random.random() for _ in range(100)]})

df.groupby("Tweets", as_index=False).first()
#    Tweets      Data
# 0       a  0.327766
# 1       b  0.677697
# 2       c  0.517186
# 3       d  0.925312
# 4       e  0.748902
# 5       f  0.353826
# 6       g  0.991566
# 7       h  0.761849
# 8       i  0.488769
# 9       j  0.501704
# 10      k  0.737816
# 11      l  0.428117
# 12      m  0.650945
# 13      n  0.530866
# 14      o  0.337835
# 15      p  0.567097
# 16      q  0.130282
# 17      r  0.619664
# 18      s  0.365220
# 19      t  0.005407
# 20      u  0.905659
# 21      v  0.495603
# 22      w  0.511894
# 23      x  0.094989
# 24      y  0.089003
# 25      z  0.511532
```

Even better, there is even a function explicitly for that, [`pandas.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html), which is about twice as fast:

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset="Tweets", keep="first")
```